# Match or synchronize two arrays to make a spelling game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm new to coding and I'm currently learning to make a spelling game with Javascript. I'm trying to make one just like Coding With Kenny's on Youtube. Here's his code with a few of my edits:

```
<body>
    <h1 id="heading">Spelling App</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <input id="input">
        <div id="buttons">
          <button id="checkButton">Check</button>
          <button id="getWordButton">get word</button>
          <button id="resetButton">next word</button>
        </div>
        <p id="correct"></p>
        <p id="incorrect"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
      var words = ["easy","apple","idea","key","awesome",
                  "spelling","eligible","cat","dog","firefly"];
      var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
      var guessbtn = document.getElementById("checkButton");
      var getwordbtn = document.getElementById("getWordButton");
      var resetbtn = document.getElementById("resetButton");

      var correct = document.getElementById("correct");
      var incorrect = document.getElementById("incorrect");

      resetbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        location.reload();
      })

      var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

      guessbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var input = document.getElementById("input").value;

        if(input==randomWord) {
          correct.innerHTML = "correct!"
        }
        else if (input!==randomWord) {
          incorrect.innerHTML = "incorrect!"
        }
      })

      getwordbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
        speech.text = randomWord;
        speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
      })
    </script>
  </body>
```

The thing is I want to use external audio files instead of `speech.text` for the `getWordButton`. I tried to make 2 arrays: 1 for the audio files and another for the answers, but it didn't work since they couldn't synchronize when picked randomly.
Here's the array I tried to add:

```
var Sounds= ["easy.mp3","apple.mp3","idea.mp3","key.mp3","awesome.mp3",
                  "spelling.mp3","eligible.mp3","cat.mp3","dog.mp3","firefly.mp3"];
oldSounds = [];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sounds.length)),
    thisSound = sounds[index];
```

I want the audio to play when the "get word" button is clicked (the word to be spelled), and the other array:

```
var words = ["easy","apple","idea","key","awesome",
                  "spelling","eligible","cat","dog","firefly"];
      var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
```

to be the answer key.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Where in the code shown are you attempting to use audio files?  What do you mean by "they couldn't synchronize"?  Can you clarify the specific problem you're observing when you test the code shown?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my question. Is it clear enough now?

Comment: Do you want to randomize or not?

Comment: Yes, I want it to pick a random audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're randomly choose from each of the two arrays.  There is a random non-zero chance that you'll get the same index in both arrays, but the odds are pretty low.

If you can guarantee that the arrays are always the same length and in the same order, just choose *one* random value and use it in both arrays:

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);
var randomWord = words[index];
var randomSound = sounds[index];
```

The ideal next step would be to not have two arrays at all, but one array of objects.  For example:

```
var words = [
  { word: 'easy', sound: 'easy.mp3' },
  { word: 'apple', sound: 'apple.mp3' },
  // etc.
];
```

Then randomly pick an object from that array:

```
var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
```

And you can use the `.word` and `.sound` properties from that object.  For example, when comparing the user input:

```
if (input == randomWord.word)
```

So instead of manually maintaining multiple arrays of values (which need to be the same length, in the same order, etc.) you can just have *one* array of objects in which the related values are kept together.

Comment: I never thought of using those way clearer methods.. thank you! Still trying to have a grasp on these new things though. Another quick question: how can I call the sound from the array of objects? Is it.. `words.sound`?

Comment: @Kate: `words` is an array, which has no `sound` property.  But any given *element* from this particular array *does* have a `sound` property.  In this example `randomWord` is a reference to an element in the array.  So `randomWord.word` would be the "word" of that element, and `randomWord.sound` would be the "sound" of that element.

Comment: Okay, got it. But does it need something else in order to play the audio? Here's the getWordBtn I mentioned earlier:
`getwordbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        randomWord.sound;
      })
`
Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kate: How to actually *play* the audio sounds like a separate concern entirely, not really in scope of the question asked above.  The question was specifically about why the code was selecting non-matching elements from the two arrays.  You might try searching on Google for how to play an audio file in JavaScript.